# Regex to add underscore between number and unit (or replace whitespace with underscore between number and unit)

Tags: regex, replace

I have a long text that contains data like:

```
23cm,
23m,
60 cm,
60 m,
```

So sometimes there is a space between number and unit. Sometimes there isn't one.
How to add an underscore in each case, so the result would be:

```
23_cm,
23_m,
60_cm,
60_m
```

The search pattern for a part of it is probably `(\d) (?:cm|m)`, but I can figure out the rest.

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: You may need a more specific answer depending on *where* you are using the regex. Please clarify.

Comment: To be consistent with your other examples I assume `'60 m,'` is to become `'60_m,'`, not `'60_m'`. Correct? If "yes", please edit. If "no", what is the rule for dropping the comma in that case?

Comment: How crazy do the numbers and units get?  `100Ω`, `-3.14 m`,  `2m^2`, `-2.3e-4eV`, `451°F` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use capturing groups. The following example uses \2 and \3 for the capturing groups. Some languages would  use $2 and $3.
See https://regex101.com/r/KxYyrb/1
input string

```
23cm, 23m, 60 cm, 60 m,
```

pattern

```
((\d+)\s?(m|cm))
```

replace using

```
\2_\3
```

output

```
23_cm, 23_m, 60_cm, 60_m,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(\d)\s?(c?m)\b
```

The replacement pattern is `$1_$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OkAkD/1).

*Details*:

- `(\d)` - Capturing group 1: a digit
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace char
- `(c?m)` - Capturing group 2: an optional `c` and an `m`
- `\b`  - a word boundary (else, the regex will match `m` in `men`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing matches of

```
(?<=\d) ?(?=c?m,)
```

with an underscore. If a space is present it is matched; else the (*zero-width*) location between the last digit and 'cm' or 'm' is matched.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXDPrg/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows. (I have enclosed the space in a character class to make it visible to the reader.)

```
(?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind    
  \d     # match a digit
)        # end positive lookbehind
[ ]?     # optionally match a space
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead  
  c?m,   # optionally match a 'c' followed by 'm,'
)        # end positive lookahead
```

If the comma is not always present replace `(?=c?m,)` with `(?=c?m\b)`, `\b` being a word boundary.